# Upload more then 5000 contacts to Telegram

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

I am trying to upload more then 5000 contacts to my Telegram account by using telethon, and I noticed that after 5000 contacts it wont upload any more-no error message just an empty list
i am using somthing like this:

```
contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id = 0, phone = "+12345678", first_name="ABC", last_name="abc")

result = client(ImportContactsRequest([contact]))
```

is there any workaround of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround according to https://www.reddit.com/r/Telegram/comments/6fta1h/getting_is_not_on_telegram_yet_would_you_like_to/ is to add 5000 contacts, wait a while (could be a long while), then add up to 5000 more.  More than 10000 total may not be possible.